# mysqldump from remote server to same remote serveritself from a local machine using python script!

Tags: python, mysql

If someone could not understand what exactly i'm trying to do, here it goes....
I use amazon cloud server, so i want to backup my database with a python script, hopefully i've got it working from command line.....

When i do a backup, it should run mysqldump on amazon server and save it into amazon server itself!! /home/abhilash/dumps/

So how do i use this command in python?? I'm new to python and trying this for a while...

`mysqldump -h 50.12.xx.xx nameofdb -u root -p |gzip -9 | ssh abhilash@50.12.xx.xx "gzip -d>/home/abhilash/a.dump"`

I want to use the above command in python, whats the easiest way?? thanks!!

Comment: Can you reduce the number of punctuation marks to just one, please?  One `!`  One `?`  One `.`  That's all that's needed.  Extra punctuation makes you look like a 10 -year old, and makes it hard to take your question seriously.

Comment: I agree in principle....that said, what if the OP _is_ a 10 year old?

Comment: @S Lott, AJ i'm sorry in that punctuation case, will not repeat this again, this is my normal style, so i'll just continue in social networking site and not here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look at [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/index.html)

It may be overkill for a single command, but as soon as your deployment/backup tasks become complex, it will surely pay off.

> Fabric is a Python (2.5 or higher) library and command-line tool for streamlining the use of SSH for application deployment or systems administration tasks.

There are a lot of good example fabfiles to learn from on [github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=filename%3Afabfile.py+mysqldump&type=Code&ref=searchresults).

To use fabric in conjunction with **mysqldump** see these blog posts:

- http://www.iangeorge.net/articles/2010/jul/22/getting-live-data-mysqldump-and-fabric/
- http://blog.archpwn.org/2010/08/09/backup-your-django-database-using-fabric/

Answer (score 0):

Use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.